# How to prevent Spock from treating null as string ("null") with ObjectMapper in unit test cases?

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, spock

I have the following Spock Unit Test example:

```
given:
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
def eventNode = mapper.valueToTree([
    person         : [
        name       : year,
        location.  : location,
    ]
])

.
.
.

where:
name  | location
'Tom' | null
```

It treats `null` in the test case as a string `"null"` and so it passes if-checks such as `if(location != null)...`

How can I make it not a string (Empty string ' ' is treated as "''")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the `location` is being parsed into a [`NullNode`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/node/NullNode.html). The `toString()` value of a `NullNode` is indeed the string `"null"` but the `textValue()` is a `null` reference. Note that even a `TextNode` produces different results for `toString()` vs. `textValue()`. You have to call the appropriate method for your test case.

```
def jacksonNull() {
    given:
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
        ObjectNode eventNode = mapper.valueToTree([
            person        : [
                name      : name,
                location  : location,
            ]
        ])
        JsonNode nameNode = eventNode.get('person').get('name')
        JsonNode locationNode = eventNode.get('person').get('location')

    expect:
        nameNode.isTextual()
        nameNode.textValue() == 'Tom'
        nameNode.toString() == '"Tom"'

        locationNode.isNull()
        locationNode.textValue() == null
        locationNode.toString() == 'null'

    where:
        name  | location
        'Tom' | null
}
```

Comment: Missing `textValue()` in the code is indeed the issue. So basically I just need to add `.textValue()` to the end of `eventNode.get('person').get('location')`. Thank you!